# CSS SVG background-size issue on Android

Tags: android, css, svg, background-image

I am using the following **CSS** code:

```
.el {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 32 32'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M29.839 10.107q0 0.714-0.5 1.214l-15.357 15.357q-0.5 0.5-1.214 0.5t-1.214-0.5l-8.893-8.893q-0.5-0.5-0.5-1.214t0.5-1.214l2.429-2.429q0.5-0.5 1.214-0.5t1.214 0.5l5.25 5.268 11.714-11.732q0.5-0.5 1.214-0.5t1.214 0.5l2.429 2.429q0.5 0.5 0.5 1.214z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 14px 14px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  color: #fff;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8gb3bzL/

The element renders correctly on all desktop browsers, and also on iPhone, iPad, Blackberry and Windows phone (that is.. everywhere).. except Android. I tried up to version 4.3 and still getting the graphic glitch:

[image]

It looks like it is clipping the background instead of resizing it. I have also tried using an external svg image, but I get the same results.

I searched everywhere (google'd, caniuse, etc) and don't see any reported bugs about this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

..for God's sake! I've been trying to work this bug out for several days, and it just struck me. The svg image **requires** that a width equal to the viewbox is set in order to work :/

Sorry guys for any inconvenience caused by my post - hopefully it helps someone that has the same issue.

```
<...>
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 32 32' **width='32' height='32'**%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M29.839 10.107q0 0.714-0.5 1.214l-15.357 15.357q-0.5 0.5-1.214 0.5t-1.214-0.5l-8.893-8.893q-0.5-0.5-0.5-1.214t0.5-1.214l2.429-2.429q0.5-0.5 1.214-0.5t1.214 0.5l5.25 5.268 11.714-11.732q0.5-0.5 1.214-0.5t1.214 0.5l2.429 2.429q0.5 0.5 0.5 1.214z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
<...>
```

Updated (working on Android) fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z8gb3bzL/1/